# Error loading Alamofire in swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am using alamofire in my project but suddenly when trying to run the app there is an error I searched over the internet and no result yet, my pod is like:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

and there error is like:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101

Comment: did you `pod install` ?

Comment: yes , and update Xcode and cocoapods , delete derived data , clean and build the project several times , and it is still found

Comment: Alamofire updated to 4.2.0. Try to update it.